# difference between I am married to and I was married to

Tags: grammar

I am confused as far as the following constructions:

1. I **am married** to US citizen
2. I **married** to US citizen
3. I **was married** to US citizen

Could someone please clear up the meaning of these sentences in terms of the tenses and how these are different from each other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An (a) is dropped in three of them. (if it was someone, we had to drop it, but here we should use it)

**The first** one means I am currently married. (married here is an adjective)

**The second** one means I married in the past, whether I am married to that person or not now.

**The third** one means sometime in the past I married to that person. (the difference between the second and third one is, the third one talks about a period in the past, not just the event of marriage in the past which happened. )

Instances:

**1**. I am married to a US citizen and we are living happily.

**2**. I married a US citizen in 1991 and we moved to the United States.

**3**. I was married to a US citizen in the duration of the second world war and then we divorced.